# adetailer in post request payload for stable diffusion api

Tags: python-requests, payload, stable-diffusion

I need to use adetailer in post request payload for stable diffusion (SD), but i can't find how to insert it in post payload. Don't find any method in SD API documentation. Please help.

Here is my paylaod to post request (commented - we try it but SD don't see ADetailer)

```
payload = {

    "init_images": [encoded_string],
    "prompt": pr,
    "denoising_strength": 0.4,
    "negative_prompt": npr,
    "batch_size": 1,
    "steps": 22,
    "cfg_scale": 7,
    "width": np.array(img).shape[1],
    "height": np.array(img).shape[0],
    #"ADetailer": [{"model": "face_yolov8n.pt"}], 
    #"adetailer": [{"model": "face_yolov8n.pt"}], 
    #"ADetailer model": "face_yolov8n.pt",
    #"adetailer model": "face_yolov8n.pt",
    "alwayson_scripts": {
        "ADetailer": {
            "args": [{
                "model": "face_yolov8n.pt",
                #"denoising_strength": 0.2
                }
                ]
        },
        "adetailer": {
            "args": [{"model": "face_yolov8n.pt", 'enable': True}, ]
        },
        "adetailer":  {"model": "face_yolov8n.pt", 'enable': True},
        "controlnet": {
            "args": [
                {
                    "input_image": encoded_string,
                    "module": "canny",
                    #'preprocessor': 'canny',
                    "model": "control_v11p_sd15_canny_fp16 [b18e0966]",
                },
                {
                    "input_image": encoded_string,
                    #"module": "lineart_standard (from white bg & black line)",
                    'preprocessor': 'lineart_standard (from white bg & black line)',
                    "model": "control_v11p_sd15_lineart_fp16 [5c23b17d]",
                    #"weight": 0.5
                },
                {
                    #'preprocessor': 'reference_only',
                    "input_image": reference,
                    "module": "reference_only"
                }
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

Tried different variations of inserting ADetailer into post request payload.

ADetailer does not appear in final picture info (like  `ADetailer model: face_yolov8n.pt, ADetailer confidence: 0.3, ADetailer dilate/erode: 4, ADetailer mask blur: 4, ADetailer denoising strength: 0.2, ADetailer inpaint only masked: True, ADetailer inpaint padding: 32`)

Answer (score 0):

look at this
https://github.com/Bing-su/adetailer/wiki/API

here is mine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRcvc.png)

```
"ADetailer": {
              "args": [
                true,
                {
                  "ad_model": "face_yolov8n.pt"
                }
              ]
            },
```